# Angular NVd3 multiBarChart

Tags: angularjs, json, nvd3.js

I would like to use the nvd3 angular multiBarChart but there is literally no documentation. I've been googling around and looking into stack overflow but can't find something that will fit my simple case. My question is on how to format the json for the multiBarChart. I have a 3 keys and each of the keys has two values. The three keys are strings, and the values are integers.

**Example:**

```
Keys: {"hi", "hello", "whatup"}
Values for each of the keys: {"hi":[10,5], "hello":[11,6], "whatup":[9,12]}.
```

I would like to show this in a stacked bar chart using nvd3. Here's something I came up with. Is this a correct way?

```
    $scope.data = [{
          values: [{
              "label" : "hi" ,
              "value" : {"A" : 10, "B" :5}
          },{
              "label" : "hello" ,
              "value" : {"A" : 11, "B" :6}
          },{
              "label" : "whatup" ,
              "value" : {"A" : 9, "B" :12}
          }]
    }];
```

It is not working

Comment: is this one? http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/multi.bar.chart.html
If not, can you post the link of library that you are using? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.data = [
            {
                key: 'hi',
                values: [{x: "A", y: 10 },{x: "B", y: 5 }]
            },
            {
                key: 'hello',
                values: [{x: "A", y: 11 },{x: "B", y: 6 }]
            },
            {
                key: 'whatup',
                values: [{x: "A", y: 9 },{x: "B", y: 12 }]
            }
];
```

I think this should work for you